# Python Requests unable to get the site even after passing headers

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape an e-commerce site Myntra but the request keeps on loading without ever returning the result. I have tried passing headers to the request with different user-agents but still, it doesn't work. If a timeout parameter is added, the request times out but no success.
Here is the sample code I'm trying to execute

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.myntra.com'
s = requests.Session()
headers = {
'authority': 'www.myntra.com',
'method': 'GET',
'path': '/',
'scheme': 'https',
'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
# dnt: 1
'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36',
}

response = s.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10).content
print(response)
```

If I try to curl the same site, I get a 403 status code with the following output.

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>
 
You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;myntra&#46;com&#47;" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;24092e17&#46;1601830542&#46;453a61c2
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Running your code works for me, I'm able to get full page. Do you run the script from some virtual hosting? Might be that your IP is blacklisted.

Comment: I tried it running on raspberry pi and on Google colab. I'm able to open the site in the browser so I don't think the IP is blacklisted.

Comment: @prasadbankar I'm running into a similar problem on a different site. I wonder if your local machine browser has some login cookies that verify you are human user. That was one difference I encountered.